# how to use jquery to remove option from select box

Tags: jquery

How to use jquery to delete opt1 row  ?  How about changing opt2 to become selected?
Note that the values are random numbers.

```
      <select name="ShippingMethod" >
        <option value="8247(random)">Opt2</option>
        <option value="1939(random)" selected="selected">Opt1</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends how you want to select it, [to remove by text](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Y5fHH/):

```
$("select[name=ShippingMethod] option").filter(function() { 
    return this.text == "Opt1"; 
}).remove();
```

[Or the selected one](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Y5fHH/3/):

```
$("select[name=ShippingMethod] option:selected").remove();
```

[Or the second one](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Y5fHH/2/):

```
$("select[name=ShippingMethod] option:eq(1)").remove();
```

[Or the last one](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Y5fHH/1/):

```
$("select[name=ShippingMethod] option:last").remove();
```

---

To just select option 2 by text, you can use the same [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) approach above:

```
$("select[name=ShippingMethod] option").filter(function() { 
    return this.text == "Opt2"; 
}).attr("selected", true);
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Y5fHH/4/).

Answer (score 1):

Quick guess as to question two

```
$('select[name=ShippingMethod]').val('19395ss');
```

Nick Carver seems to have answered the first question.